# UI-Router - templateUrl: "The content must be served over HTTPS"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use HTTPS. I need to send a `templateUrl` request, **not for a static file**, but to the router:

```
 /:lang/content/library/book/:bookId
```

Here is my `state`:

```
.state('book', {
    url: '/:lang/library/book/:bookId',
    controller: 'BookCtrl',
    templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
      return stateParams.lang + '/content/library/book/' + stateParams.bookId;
      // or: 'https://dev.mysite.com/' +  stateParams.lang + '/content/library/book/' + stateParams.bookId;
    }
  });
```

When I run my app, I get the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dev.mysite.com/en/library/book/4985459864' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://dev.mysite.com/en/content/library/book/4985459864'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

How can I send a `HTTPS` request for the `templateUrl` with `ui-router`?

Comment: To start with, wouldn't you prefer https re-direction if someone or something tries to connect to http? I don't know what you are using as a webserver, but try setting https re-direction in the config of your webserver. 2. Is the https:// absolute url working for you? 3. Try adding a '/' in front of your stateParams.lang

Comment: HTTPS absolute URL is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

> How can I send a HTTPS request for the templateUrl with ui-router?

This is the normal behaviour of ui-router. ui-router use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to resolve the protocol

Have you tried to clean the cache? if you or a user first uses a non-secure HTTP based URL and then switches to HTTPS they would have to download fresh copies of resources that had already been accessed over HTTP.